# Entity Framework Scaffold Controller returns broken page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Following the [Getting Started with EF Core on ASP.NET Core with a New database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/new-db) tutorial from Microsoft on an existing project leaves me with a very blank and non functional page for my entities:

[image: img1]

No errors are thrown, but the elements on the page don't work and are obviously not styled correctly. Here is what it should look like based on the tutorial:

[image: img2]

I guess the problem is, that I'm not starting with the template from the project ([see code](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework.Docs/tree/master/samples/core/GetStarted/AspNetCore/EFGetStarted.AspNetCore.NewDb)), but rather an existing project. I have no idea though what might be missing from my code...

Since I also don't where my problem lies, I wont just post all code from the program. If anything may be important I'm glad to add it.

---

*Sidenote:* an earlier problem with 404 errors on the same URL was occuring because the following lines were missing:

```
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```

Comment: Since obviously styling is missing, I tried to add the line `app.UseStaticFiles();`, but that didn't change anything.

Comment: What about browser console? Is there any errors? In which mode you're running Development or Production?

Comment: What does this **existing project** have? It seems you are missing required styples. I would suggest you create a new Asp.Net Core MVC project and compare the difference in `_Layout.cshtml` for two projects. Do you choose any layout while scaffloding the Controller?

Comment: The Layout file does not exist. See my comment on Adam's answer below.

Comment: @Anuraj there are no errors or even warnings (the page is very blank afterall, no js loaded). It's develop mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET Core templates are styled with Boostrap by default.

Unfortunately, it appears as though the Bootstrap files were not included in the sample project. Most likely due to a `.gitignore`. They are included if you start with a new web project using `dotnet new` or the templates included in visual studio.

[Here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework.Docs/blob/master/samples/core/GetStarted/AspNetCore/EFGetStarted.AspNetCore.NewDb/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml) you can see that the `Layout.cshtml` while in a development environment is looking for

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
```

But because the Bootstrap was not checked in with the source code, you didn't receive it.

You can find out how more information, and how to actually retrieve the dependencies through Bower in this [Microsoft Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/bower?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

However, as the page notes Bower is now deprecated for new projects. Bower itself recommends Yarn or Webpack, and Microsoft recommends LibMan or Webpack.

Lastly, there's no real need to even have a local copy of boostrap on your machine if you're just testing out the sample project. The easiest thing to do is include the CDN version regardless of the environment setting.

#### `Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml`

Replace

```
<environment include="Development">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
</environment>
<environment exclude="Development">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          asp-fallback-href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          asp-fallback-test-class="sr-only" asp-fallback-test-property="position" asp-fallback-test-value="absolute" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.min.css" asp-append-version="true" />
```

With

```
<environment include="Development">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
</environment>
<environment exclude="Development">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.min.css" asp-append-version="true" />
</environment>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

Comment: For the existing project, there is no `layout.cshtml`. The only Shared View I have is `_ValidationScriptsPartial`.
The Views folder is also missing `_ViewStart` and `_ViewImports`, which both exist in the new empty project.

Comment: I copied all files from the new project's Views folder over. Running it threw errors, because the views did not exist, so I removed all files that did not start in underscore. Then there were wrong identifiers in `_ViewImports`. After fixing those, I did actually get bootstrap import errors in the browser's console. So now I'm working on your fix.

Comment: sounds painful. for the sake of your sanity, just throw in the CDN links to get it working lol.

Comment: Final note: Your replacement lacks the substitution of the js paths. But that’s easy to find. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: Oh right sorry. When using bootstrap 4+ via CDN, the 'bundle' includes the JS. Oversight on my part, apologies.